# How to get if current language is ritht to left oriented (for uwp)

Tags: win-universal-app, right-to-left

So, that's the question. How can I get in my code behind if current language is right to left oriented.
I want my app to check if language is right to left oriented, and if it so, change main frame `FlowDirection = "RightToLeft"`. If you know better way to do it please tell me! Especially how to bind it in xaml, without code behind

***upd:***
    *Even when I set my region windows phone as ARU (United Arab Emirates), choose same language and keyboard `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo` gets culture name "en-US". What's the deal?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
bool rtl= System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft;
```

Comment: I set my phone to arabic language, chose arabic keyboard, but still getting TextInfo - en-US, and so isRightToLeft "false". Is it because of default settings on app?

Comment: maybe you need reboot?

Comment: Made a lot of them :) Still the same. I'll try to change location, see if it's work, but even if it is - I'll need to change app to RtL only by language...

Comment: wright answer. My problem was that arabic language wasn't added to my app resources.
But second part of question still open - **how to make it in XAML only?**

Comment: you can create 2 XAML pages (RTL and LTR) and navigate to right page depend of text direction